# Fragments swipe without re-creation and overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I saw many similar questions, and even took the answer from one (hide/show), but I found that when you rotate devise or turn on the night mode, embedded in the google experience, the fragment opened at this moment replaces the background of other fragments. How i can fix it? It seems that it appears if we replace `view` with another fragment instead `<fragment>`, but I'm not sure about that. Also in the API, I read that there is a `setRetainInstance` method that saves the fragment when it is rotated, but adding it to `onCreateView` has not changed anything.

///activity_main

```
<!-- Fragments Container -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    layout="@layout/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<!-- Bottom Navigation View -->

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

///MainActivity

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    final Fragment fragment1 = new MapsFragment();
    final Fragment fragment2 = new StatsFragment();
    final Fragment fragment3 = new NewsFragment();
    final Fragment fragment4 = new MoreFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    private int tabId;
    Fragment active = fragment1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadData();
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(tabId);

        switch (tabId){
            case R.id.navigation_map:
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();

                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,fragment1, "1").commit();
                return;
            case R.id.navigation_stats:
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment1, "1").hide(fragment1).commit();

                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,fragment3, "3").commit();
                return;
            case R.id.navigation_news:
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment1, "1").hide(fragment1).commit();

                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,fragment2, "2").commit();
                return;
            case R.id.navigation_more:
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment1, "1").hide(fragment1).commit();

                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,fragment4, "4").commit();
                return;
                default:
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,fragment1, "1").commit();
        }
    }
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            tabId = item.getItemId();
            //Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (tabId) {
                case R.id.navigation_map:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                    active = fragment1;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_stats:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                    active = fragment2;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_news:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                    active = fragment3;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_more:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment4).commit();
                    active = fragment4;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    private void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("tabId", tabId).commit();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        tabId = preferences.getInt("tabId",0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        saveData();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tabId",tabId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

[overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3zhP.png)

Comment: There is also a 'solution' when you set the background color of the fragments, but I don’t consider this solution to the problem because the back fragments continue to respond to pressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Before rotation, android call `onDestroy()` according to lifecycle activity, while at the same activity saving the status of all activity's view and because of this you have the status of the fragment container with the fragment already installed.
Therefore, To remove the overlapping, it is enough to hide the active fragment in `onDestroy()`. Be sure to commit `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `commit()`, otherwise it will generate an error.
 My code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    final Fragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
    final Fragment statsFragment = new StatsFragment();
    final Fragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();
    final Fragment moreFragment = new MoreFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment firstFragment;
    private int tabId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        loadData();
        setOnCreateFragment(navigation,tabId);

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            tabId = item.getItemId();
            switch (tabId) {
                case R.id.navigation_map:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(firstFragment).show(mapsFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = mapsFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_stats:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(firstFragment).show(statsFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = statsFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_news:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(firstFragment).show(newsFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = newsFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_more:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(firstFragment).show(moreFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = moreFragment;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    private void setOnCreateFragment(BottomNavigationView navigation, int tabId){

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, moreFragment, "4").hide(moreFragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, newsFragment, "3").hide(newsFragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, statsFragment, "2").hide(statsFragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mapsFragment, "1").hide(mapsFragment).commit();

        if(tabId != -1){
            switch (tabId){
                case R.id.navigation_map:
                    fm.beginTransaction().show(mapsFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = mapsFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_stats:
                    fm.beginTransaction().show(statsFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = statsFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_news:
                    fm.beginTransaction().show(newsFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = newsFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_more:
                    fm.beginTransaction().show(moreFragment).commit();
                    firstFragment = moreFragment;
                    break;
            }
            navigation.setSelectedItemId(tabId);
        } else  {
            fm.beginTransaction().show(mapsFragment).commit();
            firstFragment = mapsFragment;
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    private void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("tabId", tabId).commit();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        tabId = preferences.getInt("tabId",-1);
        //tag   = preferences.getString("tag",null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        saveData();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        fm.beginTransaction().hide(firstFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
                .setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(object : BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                        var fragment : Fragment = CategoriesFragmentKT.newInstance()
                        when (item.itemId) {
                            R.id.action_categories -> fragment= CategoriesFragmentKT.newInstance()
                            R.id.action_search -> fragment = SearchFragment.newInstance()
                            R.id.action_favorites -> fragment = FavoritesFragment.newInstance()
                        }
                        fragmentExecutor(fragment, R.id.container, false)
                        return true
                    }
                })

        fragmentExecutor(CategoriesFragmentKT.newInstance(), R.id.container, false)
```

and instead of adding the fragment, remplace them:

```
 fun fragmentExecutor(fragment: Fragment?, containerId: Int, push: Boolean) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment)

        if (push && fragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.tag)
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
```

Comment: This solution re creates fragments when switching. That doesn't suit me